# Word for half-hemisphere / quarter-sphere?

Tags: single-word-requests

A *hemisphere* is a half-sphere, for example, half the Earth: northern, southern, eastern, western hemisphere.

In a forum post related to a ESA satellite station in Argentina, I came across the phrase "having such an strategic and experienced partner on the *South West hemisphere*".

Now obviously, the *South West hemisphere* is not a hemisphere, but a half-hemisphere. Is there a word for a quarter-sphere, south as, in the geographical case, the north west, north east, south west, south east?

Maybe something like *quadrasphere*?

Comment: What is meant by "western" or "eastern" hemisphere? I don't think this distinction would carry much meaning for most speakers. On the other hand, we have the [Western world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_world), but today this has "little geographical relevance".

Comment: @Zairja Those of us who live practically on the Prime Meridian know what the western and eastern hemispheres are. The western hemisphere has longitude measured as "degrees west".

Comment: For the phrase "I have a quarter-sphere" Google Translate offers *Έχω ένα τέταρτο-σφαίρα* so it looks like the term should be tetartosphere. No-one but a Classics scholar will know what that is!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Sorry, I'm not from around here (or there, for that matter), so I wasn't aware people would make such a distinction. [This source](https://courseware.e-education.psu.edu/projection/chapter4.html) tells me that these two hemispheres may have different definitions depending on the context.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I **do** pretty much live straight south of Greenwich, but I don't extrapolate any meaning for East/West *hemisphere* from that, because it would seem "parochial".

Comment: @Zairja We routinely refer to the part of the globe containing the Americas as the "Western Hemisphere" and the part containing Europe, Africa, and Asia as the "Eastern Hemisphere". See, e.g. http://www.historicmapworks.com/Map/US/5733/Western+Hemisphere++Eastern+Hemisphere/

Comment: @Jay Thanks, I can understand that. I think one might be confused though when mixing political demarcations (Old World / New World) in a purely geographical context (satellite mapping). For example, would Portugal be in the "North West hemisphere" or the "North East"? Depending on one's definition, I would think either could be correct.

Comment: The western hemisphere has a negative longitude, of course.

Comment: Many western Europeans think they live in the western hemisphere and consider the boundary to go along the former iron curtain...

Comment: @gerrit Many Western Europeans are [wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Hemisphere).

Comment: @DavidWallace I know they are. I just mean to illustrate it's not obvious to everybody.

Comment: "West" is, of course, a relative term: Germany is west of Poland but east of France. Europe is routine referred to as part of "the West", as opposed to Asia being "the East". Europe is routinely divided into "Western Europe" and "Eastern Europe". But all of Europe is in the "Eastern Hemisphere".

Comment: @Zairja Portugal is near the western edge of the Eastern Hemisphere. Nova Scotia is near the eastern edge of the Western Hemisphere. Portugal is also in the Northern Hemisphere. Note that Northern and Southern Hemispheres are more rigidly defined because there is a natural dividing line in the north/south direction: the equater, half-way between the poles. Choice of the dividing line in the east/west direction is arbitrary because there is no such thing as the "east pole".

Comment: This doesn't even have a word in geometry?  I don't care about the earth, I just want to know what to call the chunks you get when you halve a sphere 2 or 3 times.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: "A precise English term conveying this idea — parallel to the terms spherical, hemispherical — is wanted. Will any Greek scholar supply it? *Tetartospherical* is a long word to use, and I hate *verba sesquipedalia*; still, we require a term for a shape very common in the carapaces of Crustacea." - [Palaeontographical Society Monographs, 1867](http://books.google.com/books?id=c7gyAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA193&ots=ZVNb_SqRsb&pg=PA194#v=onepage&q=tetartospherical&f=false)

Comment: If you take a sphere and cut it half across on each of its three axes, you have eight hemidemisemipheres. It’s the reasonable way to do it. Now you just have to figure out what to name each one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such term. You could use *semihemisphere*, but this is not a geographical term as far as I'm aware. Evidence of absence is always difficult and doesn't make a rewarding answer.

I would suggest a different term altogether like *area* or *region*. If you insist on the "quarter of the earth" sense, then ***quadrant*** would fit your needs.

Carlo_R has an interesting point, but *quadrant* is in use, geographically, and is a word that most speakers will glean meaning from. Some examples include "[Mapping World Heritage Sites](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/education/activity/mapping-world-heritage/?ar_a=1)":

> Use a dry erase marker to draw, or have a volunteer draw, the Equator and prime meridian. Then label each **quadrant** of the map with its hemispheric identifier: NE, NW, SE, and SW.

"[Geographic Coordinate System](http://www.ecu.edu/cs-cas/plan/upload/GeographicCoordinateSystem.pdf)":

> The origin of the graticule (0,0) is defined by where
>   the equator and prime meridian intersect. The globe
>   is then divided into **four geographical quadrants** that
>   are based on compass bearings from the origin.
>   North and south are above and below the equator,
>   and west and east are to the left and right of the
>   prime meridian.

[Earth quadrant](http://onelook.com/?w=earth+quadrant&ls=a) from *Webster's* (1913):

> n. a fourth of the earth's circumference.

Comment: I disagree with "quadrant". In fact one curved quarter of the hemisphere is already a spherical quadrant of 90°, hence "quadrant" cannot be a quarter of a sphere. However, congratulations for "area" and "region".

Comment: +1 for quadrant which makes sense since the "sphere" in question is inevitably a flattened 2-D translation. I would also mention [octant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(solid_geometry)) which is its 3-D equivalent.

Comment: A quadrant of a circle is the area defined by 90 degrees of arc. So I think most geometers, at least, would think of a "quadrant" of a sphere as being a slice made up of 90 degrees of arc in one direction and 360 degrees in the other, not 180 and 180.

Comment: @What Carlo_R said. Rightly or wrongly, I would normally understand a [quadrant of a sphere](http://www.ai.sri.com/geovrml/protos/GeoElevationGrid/geoeg.gif) to look like the diagram in that link (one **eighth** of the total sphere).

Comment: I like "semihemisphere" or variations thereof. It's an obvious plagiarism of "semihemiquaver" from music. I don't think it's a recognized term, but it ought to be.

Comment: Following the double greek roots of Hemisphere, I'd go with Tetartisphere or something

Answer (score 4):

There may be no official word for this in Geometry, but borrowing from *semihemidemisemiquaver*, a 1\128th note in music, you might use:

> semihemisphere

Comment: I like that better. It makes more sense to slice the sphere in half at each of its three orthogonal axes.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you assume *South West hemisphere* is not correct? A sphere can be divided in half along any diameter, not just the Equator or zero meridian.  I don't (obviously) know the original report, but it may easily be that the ESA meant the half of the world including Mexico and South Africa, but excluding Canada and Sri Lanka.

Comment: My objection to *South West hemisphere* is that hemisphere is 50% of the planet whereas *South west* (something) is 25% of the planet. I was quoting from a forum post, more specifically a Facebook comment on a ESA news item.

Comment: @gerrit: My question is why do you assume *Southwest* is 25% while *South* is 50%? Both are arbitrary directions, and so both can equally refer to a hemisphere.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't think of that option. But such a hemisphere would not go along either lines of latitude or lines of longitude. I have some difficulties imagining what it would look like. I'm pretty sure that in the context where I saw it, it meant 25%.

Comment: Conceptually a "southwest hemisphere" should also include the northeast, if you were looking at a map.

Answer (score 2):

If you want what would amount to one of eight pieces (rather than four) in three dimensions, and one of 2^n th in n dimensions, in mathematics, the term for the higher dimensional analogues of quadrant is *orthant*. This means—for three dimensions—one of the eight subsets, each consisting of triples with the same sign pattern. So you could say an orthant of the sphere, and anyone who knows the more general meaning of orthant would understand immediately.

Perhaps, *bi-orthant*  (a set consisting of two, presumably contiguous, orthants) *of a sphere* would be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "Tetartosphere." (Tetarto - Greek: one-fourth)

> **tetartosphere**
> (mathematics, rare) One quarter of a sphere; a quadrant.
> *North America is in the northwestern tetartosphere.*

[[Word Sense]](https://www.wordsense.eu/tetartosphere/)

Comment: please support your answer with some credible sources.

Comment: Yes, sounds interesting, but need the background on tetrato to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Qudrasphere - Hemisphere is half of the world, so quadrasphere could be one fourth of the world.